# Java inheritance is Super content copied?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am really trying to understand how does inheritance works,

**say we have Class A and B, B extends A, A contains some Attributes (reference type and also primitive type) set on public and methods**

are these attribute and methods copied into class B ? i did read that methods aren't copied but get accessed by reference.

How about the reference type attributes that are inherited when we create an instance of B ? they have to take some space in memory and where is that reference stored ? in class A or B ? and what about primitive type do they get copied into class B and are they in the same place where others attributes of B are found ?

or when you create an object of class B, you create in fact an object of A and B and they maintain some relation ?

Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Well, if by copied you mean inherited, then yes. I think you're a bit confused between objects and classes. When you create an instance of `B`, there's a single object containing both A's and B's fields.

Comment: The superclass and its methods and fields are **part of** the subclass. When you create a subclass, it will first creates its **base** (i.e. the stuff from the parent class) and then build itself ontop of it. So, as others said, there is only one instance. Namely the subclass, which includes everything thats specified in the superclass as its base.

Comment: what i meant is  if i create a new instance of B, the variable points to the object which contain all the data from B, now if B inherited from A, is the from A found also in the same place as data from B.

Comment: The data from A and B are immediately next to each other in one combined object.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an Animal class:

```
public class Animal {
    private String _name;

    public Animal(String name) { _name = name;}

    public String getName() {return _name;}
}
```

Now there is a Dog class:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super("Dog");
    }
}
```

Now if you do like this:

```
 Animal dog = new Dog();
 System.out.println(dog.getName());
```

This is how you make the variable name available from `Dog` class to `Animal`.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about polymorphism.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. "*How about the reference type attributes that are inherited when we create an instance of B? they have to take some space in memory and where is that reference stored? in class A or B?*" and "*when you create an object of class B, you create in fact an object of A and B and they maintain some relation*" clarify the OP's concerns. Nothing to do with how to access properties of a supertype from the subtype. Also, using getters like this over time tends to result in over exposure & segregated logic. Although it works, it's not OOP - it's procedural.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I thought `Animal dog = new Dog()` is [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), I might be mistaken.

Comment: i think i was maybe not precise about my question, say the instance of B ? the variable points to the object which holds all the attributes of B, now what i asked is when there is a inheritance, are attributes from A found also there ?

Comment: @hopala Yes. Memory allocation is only done when you create an object. And yes there you will find the references of the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

> Java inheritance is Super content copied?
>
> am really trying to understand how does inheritance works,
>
> say we have Class A and B, B extends A, A contains some Attributes
>   (reference type and also primitive type) set on public and methods
>
> are these attribute and methods copied into class B ?

The public attributes and methods are inherited by the sub-class `B`. Consider classes `A` and its sub-class `B`:

```
public class A {

    public int aNumber = 99;
    public StringBuilder aString = new StringBuilder("sb");
    private String privateVar = "private stuff";

    public A() {
    }

    public A(int i, StringBuilder s) {
        aNumber = i;
        aString = s;
    }

    public int getMyNumber() {
        return aNumber*2;
    }
    public StringBuilder getMyString() {
        return aString.append("!!");
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return aNumber + " : " + aString;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    public B() {
    }

    public B(int i, StringBuilder s) {
        super(i, s);
    }
}
```

The following class has some code to test the above two class's behavior, in terms of inheritance:

```
public class TestingInheritance {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        A a = new A(3, new StringBuilder("test1"));
        System.out.println("A: " + a);

        B b = new B();
        System.out.println("b: " + b);
        System.out.println("b.aNumber: " + b.aNumber);
        System.out.println("b.getMyNumber: " + b.getMyNumber());
        System.out.println("");

        B b2 = new B(2, new StringBuilder("xx"));
        System.out.println("b2: " + b2);
        System.out.println("b2.aString: " + b2.aString);
        System.out.println("b2.getMyString: " + b2.getMyString());

        //System.out.println("Private: " + b.privateVar);
    }
}
```

**The Output:**

```
A: 3 : test1
b: 99 : sb
b.aNumber: 99
b.getMyNumber: 198

b2: 2 : xx
b2.aString: xx
b2.getMyString: xx!!
```

**Discussion:**

There are two classes `A` and `B`. The class `B` extends `A`. `A` is the super class and `B` is its sub-class. The two classes have two constructors each- one the default no-arg constructor and a constructor that takes arguments.

The class `A` has public attributes of type primitive and reference: `int aNumber` and `java.lang.StringBuilder aString`. There are public methods `getMyNumber`, `getMyString` and an `java.lang.Object` class's overridden `toString`. Note there is also a private variable `privateVar`.

The code details from `TestingInheritance`:

(i) Consider:

```
B b = new B();
```

This constructs an instance of `B`. This inherits the attributes and methods of its super-class `A`.

```
System.out.println("b: " + b); // b: 99 : sb
```

The newly created object `b` has the inherited attribute values from its super-class `A`; hence it prints the attribute default values from its overridden `toString` method. Note the default values defined in class `A` for the attributes are `99` and a `StringBuilder` object with its string value "sb".

The following print the attribute and method results from the inherited `A`, using the default attribute values.

```
System.out.println("b.aNumber: " + b.aNumber); // 99
System.out.println("b.getMyNumber: " + b.getMyNumber()); // 198
```

(ii) Consider:

```
B b2 = new B(2, new StringBuilder("xx"));
```

This constructs an instance of `B` with the supplied parameters: `2` and `new StringBuilder("xx")`. Note in the class `B`'s constructor the statement `super(i, s)`; this is required. And, if not specified there will be compile-time error.

```
System.out.println("b2: " + b2); // 2 : xx
```

This prints the supplied parameter values in the `B` class's constructor, which are in turn passed to the `A` class's constructor with arguments: `super(i, s)`. When an instance of the `B` class is created (using the constructor) the `A` class's constructor runs, *first* - see the `super(...)` statement (and it was the first statement within the constructor code).

The following print the inherited attribute value and method return value.

```
System.out.println("b2.aString: " + b2.aString); // xx
System.out.println("b2.getMyString: " + b2.getMyString()); // xx!!
```

(iii) Finally, the following statement if un-commented the program `TestingInheritance` will not compile. There will be an error: `TestingInheritance.java:18: error: privateVar has private access in A`.

```
System.out.println("Private: " + b.privateVar);
```

But, the private attribute can be accessed in `B` thru a public method defined in class `A`.